# My Hp Pavilion Laptop Dual boot with ubuntu 14.04 is overheating

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, overheating

I am having an HP pavilion g6 2320tx

AMD Radeon 7670m
i5 
4gb RAM

Dual Boot with windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04LTS

While Working on ubuntu temperature shoots up to 85C and while in windows temperature is around 48C

I have checked the background tasks , and everything seems fine

Is there any solution available ?

Comment: CPU temperature, right?

Comment: yes, Cpu temperature , i have turned off my gpu